# How do I run my local Rails instance on a domain that isn't "localhost"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, alias, hosts

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 on Mac Yosemite.  I’m trying to set up an alias for my local machine, so that I can enter “http://devbox.example.com:3000/” in my browser and have my local Rails instance serve the pages.  But I can’t seem to do this.  I have set this up in my /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       devbox.example.com
```

But when I start my Rails server (“rails s”), I can visit “http:///localhost:3000/“ just fine, but when I try and visit “http://devbox.example.com:3000/“, I get an “Unable to connect” error.  What’s stranger, when the server is running, pinging the alias I have set up resolves to 127.0.0.1 …

```
localhost:myapp davea$ ping devbox.example.com
PING devbox.example.com (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
```

What do I need to do in Rails to get my server to run on the alias I have set up?

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking but ngrok might help you: https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rails s -b 0.0.0.0`. The `-b` or bind option will allow you to set the ip address that the rails server binds to. If you had multiple connectors, you could set a specific one.

Comment: In case you want to run on port 80: `sudo rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80`